# Парсинг по списку в RichTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, json.net

Сделал парсер json на одном сайте, теперь мне нужно реализовать список в richTextBox1 ссылок, откуда парсить и выводить все полученные данные в richTextBox2.

Мой код:

```
string link = richTextBox1; //Ссылки

string json = WebClient.DownloadString(".....metadata?q=") + link;

RichTextBox1: 
link //Первая ссылка 
link1 //Вторая ссылка
//И тд...


RichTextBox2: //Данные который я должен получить с каждой ссылки
link: Value1
link1: Value2 
//И тд...
```

Как сделать, чтобы он поочереди брал ссылки из richTextBox1 и выводил значения в richTextBox2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблему решил путем цикла foreach и Split.

```
string link = richTextBox1.Text;
string[] value = link.Split();

foreach (var pair in value)
{
//code
}
```